# jQuery Ajax FormPlugin: Grab Ajax Response

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I am using the [ajax form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started) to handle my ajax submissions, like so..

```
 // Submit Form New User
  $('#setAdminUser').ajaxForm({
   beforeSubmit : validateForm,
   success: ajaxSuccess
     });

    // Ajax success callback
  function ajaxSuccess(){
  // Do processing here
           // Create div, containing the response from my ajax call
           var str = ''
           str += '<div id="recordCreated">'
           str += '<h2> Record ' + data + 'd</h2>'
           str += '</div>'

           // Add div to container on page
           $("#userAdded").html(str)
  }
```

What I am looking to do, is grab the response data from my ajax call so I can use it in my function ajaxSuccess, as `sgiwb` above. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the response as parameter to the function:

```
function ajaxSuccess(response) {
    // use the response here
}
```

Quote from the [documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object):

> **success**: Callback function to be
>   invoked after the form has been
>   submitted. If a 'success' callback
>   function is provided it is invoked
>   after the response has been returned
>   from the server. It is passed the
>   responseText or responseXML value
>   (depending on the value of the
>   dataType option).